# Firefox font vertical misalignment?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

So I use this webfont called Gagalin (Regular) on a design of mine and it works fine in Chrome and Edge. However, when I look at it in FireFox I get a very strange vertical misalignment (image below). Also the `@font-face` rule I use has always worked before (also in FireFox) just not with this font because the other webfont I'm using is aligned correctly. Any ideas on how I could fix this? I am assuming it has something to do with the font or?

**EDIT** maybe this is not the best place to ask but I don't really know where else to

**CODE**

I have magin, padding and line-height reset set + I have `normalize.min.css` included with `h1` margin reset by me explicitly to `0` to override the normalize margin. Also the line-height for the header h1 is set at 1 again.

[Dropbox link to the font files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dyuwqm8wdax20c3/AAC9pUbyFW6OEqFxdFTeSaP-a?dl=0)

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Gagalin';
    src:url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.svg#Gagalin-Regular) format('svg'),
        url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal
}

* {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 3vm;
    font-size: 3vmin;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Gagalin';
    margin: 0;
}

header h1 {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Tried removing all fonts but the woff ones and the issue remains the same

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Gagalin';
    src:url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/gagalin/Gagalin-Regular.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal
}
```

**IMAGES**

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Edge]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right for those who want to know I was able to fix this by opening the font in Birdfont , exporting it and reconverting it. I don't really know why Firefox was messing it up whereas the other browsers didn't have a grudge with it but it is working now.

Thanks for your time and answers

Comment: You are welcome. So I guess it turned out to be a font (baseline definition) problem. Reconverting probably fixed this.

Comment: You should mark this the answer – that's cool by Stackoverflows standards, I guess

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a different default line-height.. Setting the line-height explicitly could fix this. Any chance we could see your code, to verify this?

Same goes for margin and padding. I see an explicit margin of zero, but I see no explicit padding of zero.

Note that the rules at Stack Overflow require you to send some code, so we can test/reproduce the problem.

Comment: line-height is already explicitly set at 1. I have added a screenshot to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all fonts, or all fonts but woff or woff2 to see if it is a font inconsistency/baseline problem.

Comment: Tried it and updated the post. The issue remains the same in FireFox

Comment: I have it is not a padding issue. Otherwise it would also show up in the inspector but the height of the element is correct and matches with chrome and edge though the font still misaligns